# gvNix: Showing entities based on user roles

Tags: spring, spring-roo, gvnix

I'm using gvNix to create my web application and I used typicalsecurity addon to enable email verification and sign up...etc.
But now I want only the **admin** to see all the entities on the menu, the normal user can only access some entities. I have more than one role.

I tried to google typicalsecurity addon but I was only able to find the first step, which is installing the addon and integrate it with the app.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the menu visibility based on roles you have to use the menu utility offered by gvNIX. In gvNIX run `help menu` for more info, or read the spanish guide at http://www.gvnix.org/assets/doc/gvnix-2.0.0.M1-reference-docs/#comandos-del-add-on-web-menu

For a complete security you should use Spring Security to limit which actions (controller methods or service methods) can be invoked by each role.